# Either Infinite loop or missing dependency in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to apply a function on the previous state every time there is a new state.
User case: an user establishes a connection to a server. I create a WebSocket object and put it into webSocketInstance. When an user enters his usename I add the name to Redux and it causes re-render of the component which is okay. Now as he has the username I want him to reconnect with a new url(also this part of reconnection logic). So I want him to close the previous connection and open a new one.

```
export default function GameKeeper() {
  // Redux states here
  const { adminWsUrl, clientWsUrl, clientCode, playerName } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.hosting
  );
  const [webSocketInstance, setWebSocketInstance] = useState<WebSocket>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (webSocketInstance) {
      webSocketInstance.close();
    }
    if (adminWsUrl) {
      setWebSocketInstance(new WebSocket(adminWsUrl));
    } else if (clientWsUrl && playerName) {
      setWebSocketInstance(new WebSocket(`${clientWsUrl}${playerName}/`));
    } else if (clientWsUrl && !playerName) {
      setWebSocketInstance(new WebSocket(clientWsUrl));
    }
  }, [adminWsUrl, clientWsUrl, playerName]);
  
  
 return (
  ...
 );
 
}
```

The current code gives me a warning that webSocketInstance is not in useEffect dependencies. If I add it, I get infinite loop.

Comment: The ellipses are making me nervous - I'd suggest posting the entire `useEffect`. It could be a case of splitting the data flow up into more state and effects so that you can decouple everything properly. Additionally, you might benefit from a `useReducer` approach instead of `useState`.

Comment: I totally agree with @lawrence-witt... what *else* is possibly triggering this effect to run.

Comment: @lawrence-witt, DrewReese "useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one." that's from reactjs.org seems like exactly what I need, thanks

Comment: True, a reducer function handles more complex state updates, but `useState` also has a functional update as well, basically minus the "action". In either case though they are to be pure function without side-effects. I think this issue is more about the effect of opening/closing sockets than it is about updating state.

Comment: I've come across a few questions like this on SO and sockets and the resultant working solution usually involves ***not*** storing the socket in state as there always seems to be a looping issue. Have you tried a react ref or global variable (*in the file the component is defined in*) to hold the socket instance?

Comment: Nope, I haven't, but if summarize my problem is: I have a state1 and every time state2 is changed I want to update state1 by before apply a method on state1. It makes no sense as usually(unless you have a complex logic) states are primitives(roughly speaking) but with WebSockets seems it should be a bit different way. I'll try different solutions and then post the code

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic template for how I'd go about setting up a `useReducer` to handle this. I can't really think of a good way to do this with just `useState` without also utilising some mutative state (i.e. `useRef`) to hold the Web Socket instead. The drawback there of course is you've escaped React's state system altogether and can no longer watch your socket for updates.

```
function wsReducer(wsInstance, action) {
  if (action.type === "reset") {
    wsInstance && wsInstance.close();
    return new WebSocket(action.payload);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const { adminWsUrl, clientWsUrl, clientCode, playerName } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.hosting
  );
  const [wsInstance, dispatch] = useReducer(wsReducer, null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = (() => {
      if (adminWsUrl) return adminWsUrl;
      if (clientWsUrl && playerName) return `${clientWsUrl}${playerName}/`;
      if (clientWsUrl && !playerName) return clientWsUrl;
      return false;
    })();

    if (url) {
      dispatch({ type: "reset", payload: url });
    }
  }, [adminWsUrl, clientWsUrl, playerName]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Also, some [recommended reading](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#decoupling-updates-from-actions) - particularly the stuff on decoupling updates/actions and using `useReducer` in this context. I'd suggest trying to get through the whole thing, it was really useful for me when I started doing functional React.